# Specifying a parent class while using send to call from an instance of an object in ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, metaprogramming, multiple-inheritance

So, as far as I know, the way to simulate/have multiple inheritances in ruby is through modules (if there is another/better pls let me know ), so let's say I have the following structure/architecture:

```rb
class A
    def foo
        p "Foo from A"
    end
end

module B
    def foo
        p "Foo from B"
    end
end

class C < A
    include B
end

c = C.new

c.send('foo')
```

The code above as a lot of you already know will print `Foo from B`, because the `send` function will look inside the class `C` and since there is no definition for the `foo` function it will look for that function within `C` ancestors, so my question (maybe not a smart one), is there any way to specify/prioritize an ancestor of `C` while calling `send`/or a workaround for that behavior (don't want to instantiate the parent class I need it in this way)? I couldn't find anything in the documentation of [the send function](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send).

**EDITED**

The architecture shown above is a legacy code, my intention is to find a workaround in order to not be disruptive with the existing code (that's why I have that architecture)

Thx in advance .

Comment: The question arises: why are you including B if you don't want to use B's methods? A and B are probably doing too much. Or A#foo and B#foo are unrelated and you have a naming conflict.

Comment: B and A are already being used and for some reason, both contain definitions for 'foo' and of course more stuff, I am trying to achieve that behavior on top of that definition in order to not be disruptive with the legacy code already in place @Schwern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Prepend Your "Preferred" Module

It's unclear why you're trying to do things this way, as you seem to have landed on a desired solution without clearly defining the problem it's meant to solve. Since A and B both have a #foo method, which one is called first will depend on the order in which the method lookup is performed. For example, with your current code:

```rb
c.class.included_modules
#=> [B, Kernel]

c.class.ancestors
#=> [C, B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

In your current code, `c.send 'foo'` will call B#foo because it will be the first object in the lookup that can `respond_to? :foo`. The only way to change the lookup is to explicitly call A#foo from within the C class, or rewrite A as a module and use [Module#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend) to insert it at the front of the lookup before B or C. For example:

```rb
module A
    def foo; p 'Foo from A'; end
end

module B
    def foo; p 'Foo from B'; end
end

class C
    include B
    prepend A
end

C.ancestors
#=> [A, C, B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

C.new.foo
#=> "Foo from A"
```

Comment: thx for the answer @Todd A. Jacobs as I mentioned in my comment above I was looking for a workaround in order to not be disruptive with the existing legacy code, unfortunately, seems like my guess was correct and in the end, I would need to change some definitions in order to get the proper behavior, thx again 

Answer (score 1):

The question arises: why are you including B if you don't want to use B's methods? I can see two scenarios.

- You want to pick bits of A and B: they're doing too much.
- A#foo and B#foo are unrelated.

---

The problem with multiple-inheritance is you're never quite sure which method is going to be called. Modules mitigate this, but because they pollute your namespace the problem remains. Duck typing makes this worse, lacking signatures if two unrelated modules happen to have the same name they will interfere with each other.

You can do [fancy tricks to reorder your ancestry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555601/14660), but there's no guarantee the problem won't come up again, and the ancestry tree remains implicit and complex inviting future mistakes.

This is best avoided entirely by using [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(computing)) instead.

```
class B
  def foo
    p "Foo from B"
  end
end

class C < A
  attr_accessor :b

  def initialize
    @b = B.new
  end
end
```

Now you disambiguate what you're doing by calling `c.b.foo`. You can also rename the method if you want to hide `b`.

```
class C < A
  attr_accessor :b

  def initialize
    @b = B.new
  end

  def b_foo
    b.foo
  end
end
```

---

If A#foo and B#foo are related, and you only want *part* of B, then B is doing too much. Extract the conflicting piece from ***both*** A and B into a separate module.

For example, let's say A talks to a service. B changes how A talks to a service, but you want to keep A's login method. Extract the login part from both.

```
class A
  # no login method
end

module A::Login
  def login
  end
end

module B::Login
  def login
  end
end

class C < A
  include A::Login
  include B
end
```

Now C picks up functionality from A, B, and A style login.

This does mean users of A must pick a login module. Again, this is probably better solved with delegation.

```
class A
  attr_writer :authenticator

  def authenticator_class
    A::Authenticator
  end

  # Defaults to A::Authenticator.new
  def authenticator
    @authenticator ||= authenticator_class.new
  end

  def login
    authenticator.login
  end
end

class A::Authenticator
  def login
  end
end

class B::Authenticator
  def login
  end
end

class C < A
  # Switch to using B for authentication.
  def authenticator_class
    B::Authenticator
  end
end
```

Now A has a default for authentication and it can be *explicitly* overridden either for the whole class, or for a single object.

```
c.authenticator = D::Authenticator.new
```

---

When to use a module, subclass, or delegate has no clear answer. But when you're getting into method clashes it's probably time to switch to delegation.

Comment: thx for the deep explanation @Schwern, your guess is right A and B are doing too much but I didn't want to change too much code there, at the end seems like in order to get the proper solution I would need to change the architecture thx again 

Comment: @r4cc00n A minimal change might be to define `class B::Authenticator` which includes B. Then you can transition to delegation one class at a time while retaining existing code which includes B.

Comment: yup I was thinking on include a node between B and the classes that include B (by node I mean another class, thinking in the hierarchy as a graph ) but that class will have probably the abstraction that is really being used from B

Comment: That change of course will impact but I think is the less of the evils in my case , thx again for the support 

Answer (score 0):

> The architecture shown above is a legacy code, my intention is to find a workaround in order to not be disruptive with the existing code (that's why I have that architecture)

As a (quick and dirty) workaround, you can use [`super_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Method.html#super_method-method) and [`call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Method.html#call-method) to invoke `A#foo`:

```
c = C.new
c.method(:foo).super_method.call
#=> "Foo from A"
```

You could also use a loop to find the "correct" method dynamically:

```
m = c.method(:foo)
m = m.super_method until m.owner == A
m.call
#=> "Foo from A"
```

Note that bypassing the ancestors and invoking a method directly this way can lead to unexpected results.